# What is the best way to read a string as a command with a whitespace separated argument?

Tags: c, linux

I'm currently writing a primitive shell that lets user input few basic commands: `ls`, `cat` etc. I'm taking from the user an input like: `ls /home/someUser/someDirectory` and storing this in a character array, say `input`. I've written a few little such functions `ls`, `cat` etc. that take an argument and print to `stdout` the expected result.

What I'd like to know is: what would be the best way to break this `input` up into a command and argument? For the said example, I'd like to get two different chunks: `ls` and `/home/someUser/someDirectory`, so that I can check what command the user wants to execute with what argument. Sure, I can maintain pointers and check the first few characters of the array and compare them and then proceed to the character after whitespace and parse the argument accordingly, but that would be very tedious and inefficient. Is there a better way to do this, possibly an in-built function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try with `strtok()`.

Comment: [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html)

Comment: Everything in C is tedious. That is why it is powerful.

Comment: While you're dealing with space-separated inputs, `strtok()` (or, preferably, `strtok_r()` or Microsoft's `strtok_s()`) is fine. However, a real shell handles `cat *>../pygmalion` where there's no space between the `*` and the I/O redirection.  Since `strtok()` zaps the delimiter, you will ultimately end up using something other than `strtok()`. You could head off trouble now using (`strspn()` or) `strcspn()` or `strpbrk()`, and working with 'strings' marked by start pointer and length, or start pointer and pointer to one beyond end. These don't tamper with the input, unlike `strtok()`.

Comment: Is whitespace always a separator?  `cat "abc 123.txt"`?  Really think code need to have some explicit rules about parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **split(char *const source, const char *const delimiter)
{
    size_t length;
    char **list;
    size_t count;
    char  *pointer;
    char  *token;
    void  *saved;

    if ((source == NULL) || (delimiter == NULL))
        return NULL;

    list    = NULL;
    pointer = source;
    count   = 0;
    while ((token = strtok(pointer, delimiter)) != NULL)
    {
        saved = realloc(list, (1 + count) * sizeof(*list));
        if (saved == NULL)
            goto abort;
        length      = strlen(token);
        list        = saved;
        list[count] = malloc(1 + length);
        if (list[count] == NULL)
            goto abort;
        strcpy(list[count], token);
        pointer = NULL;

        count++;
    }
    saved = realloc(list, (1 + count) * sizeof(*list));
    if (saved == NULL)
        return list;
    list        = saved;
    list[count] = NULL;

    return list;
abort:
    while (count != 0)
        free(list[count--]);
    free(list);

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    size_t k;
    char string[] = "example string with spaces";
    char **list;

    list = split(string, " ");
    if (list == NULL)
        return -1;
    k = 0;
    while (list[k] != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", list[k]);
        free(list[k]);

        k++;
    }
    free(list);
    return 0;
}
```

The split function will return an array of `char` pointers which contain the tokens, and have a sentinel `NULL` pointer that tells you where the end of the list is.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char example_input[80] = "ls /home/user/directory/file.ext";
  const char s[2] = "-";
  char *token = strtok(example_input, " ");

  /* walk through other tokens */
  while( token != NULL ){
     printf("%s\n", token );
     token = strtok(NULL, s);
  }

  return(0);
}
```

Escape characters will be somewhat trickier.

If you only need to divide the string into command and argument this may work:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void cmd_ls(const char *arg){
  printf("lsing %s\n",arg);
}

void cmd_pwd(const char *arg){
  printf("pwding %s\n",arg);
}

int main(){
  char example_input[80] = "psdwd /home/user/directory/file.ext";
  const char s[2] = "-";

  //Find command, assuming it ends at the first space

  //Points to first space in string, will eventually point to beginning of
  //command
  char *command  = strchr(example_input, ' ');

  //Will point to beginning of argument
  char *argument = NULL;

  //If command is not NULL, then there is at least one space, so the string has
  //the form "<COMMAND> X" where X is either '\0' (string terminator) or another
  //character. If the string contains a space, edit it so that there is a
  //terminator after the command. If there is an argument, return a pointer to
  //its beginning (which may be a space).
  if(command!=NULL){
    *(command) = '\0';       //Terminate command string
    if(*(command+1)!='\0')   //If there are argument characters, point to them
      argument = command+1;
  }
  command = example_input;   //Point command to beginning of command


  //Do I recognise this command?
  if(strcmp(command,"ls")==0){
    cmd_ls(argument);
  } else if(strcmp(command,"pwd")==0) {
    cmd_pwd(argument);
  } else {
    printf("Unrecognised command!\n");
  }

  return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it simply using scanf. you have to read the input until you get a '\n' character.
the code to do it will be :

```
scanf("%[^\n]", string);
```

the total string will be stored in the array string. you can do further string processing to extract the required data.